# vlook up for multi combination value

Tags: excel

Friend.

I have sheet1 like below

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr
```

A   10  15  13  10

B   11  11  15  12

C   12  13  15  14

D   12  10  10  15

In Sheet 2! i have 2 scroll scroll down list in cells made by data validation.fist one is in A1 with the values A, B and C, in A2 cell with the values Jan,Feb,Mar.

What i need on this, if i select A and Jan from scroll down list. i need to show the value as '10' in A3 Cell

I tried VLook up with my limited knowlege but i can provide only one value in Lookup value and array.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide vlookup a number of column to return as variable, which you may get as a return value of match function.

**Sheet1** has populated range **A1:E5**, where first row contains names of months (range **A1:E1**). **Sheet2** has only values in two cells **A1** and **A2**.

You need to find in which column of Sheet1 is a month, that is done by

```
match(a2, Sheet1!A1:E1, 0)+1
```

and find the value with **VLOOKUP**.
The final formula would be

```
=vlookup(a1, sheet1!a1:e10, match(a2, sheet1!A1:e1, 0)+1, false)
```

**EDIT:** The first time I messed Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: could you please explain little more. I have tried it like equation what you have given. buy it's not working.

Comment: See the amended code, for more details about match and vlookup see MSDN and Google. If that is not a solution you looked for, then you need to provide clearer description.